# How to format NVMe drive in Linux suitable for raid 1 and lvm on xen Host

Tags: raid, lvm, xen, ssd, nvme

I want to create a software raid on two identical SSDs

How do I create partitions and format them optimal?

```
lsblk

nvme0n1            259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk
nvme1n1            259:1    0 953.9G  0 disk
```

I probably have to use `fdisk` or `parted` to create partitions. What options do I need? Is this enough?

```
parted /dev/nvme0n1

(parted) mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%
(parted) set 1 raid on
```

The disks both have 1tb and
I also need a small boot partition with 500mb

Comment: The task as it's stated (to have RAID and LVM) is so generic so almost anything you do will be "suitable". This makes me suspicious, are there additional hidden constraints? Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with being inexperienced, and to learn *don't hesitate to experiment*. Try it and see if it works for you. So yes, you may continue `pvcreate` and then `vgcreate` with the RAID volume and that's it.

Comment: Thanks. That's is a releive 

Comment: You don't need to create any partitions at all for raid. You can do so if you need partitions for other reasons, but the raid, or lvm for that matter,  doesn't care if partitions or complete disks are used.

Comment: If you need a small boot partition your first step to create a single 100% partition was already moot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: no, this answer doesn't help. My server is already running on two HDDs and i want to migrate to SSDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cfdisk` to create a GPT partition table like this:

```
# fdisk /dev/nvme0n1 -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953,87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HALR-00000              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BD545B1F-C8D2-4145-B2C9-379506C67728

Device           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048       4095       2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/nvme0n1p2    4096    1028095    1024000   500M Linux RAID
/dev/nvme0n1p3 1028096 2000408575 1999380480 953,4G Linux RAID
```

The same on `nvme1n1`

Then create the raid with mdadm. I already have two raids on the HDDs.

```
cat /proc/mdstat
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      523264 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      7813368128 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 14/59 pages [56KB], 65536KB chunk
```

to create new raids md3 and md4:

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md3 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/nvme0n1p2 /dev/nvme1n1p2
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md4 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/nvme0n1p3 /dev/nvme1n1p3
```

md3 is reserved for /boot, so create a new physical volume on md4:

```
pvcreate /dev/md4
```

and a new volume group with

```
lvcreate vg1 /dev/md4
```